# How to use start and limit on DataTables in Laravel for mobile API

Tags: laravel, mobile, datatables, pagination

```
public function listRemarks(ListRequest $request)
    {
        $listRemarks = $this->remarkservice->listRemarks($request);
        $totalRecords = $listRemarks->count();
        $limit = $request->length ?? 10;
        $start = $request->start ?? 0;
        $listRemarks->offset($start)->limit($limit);
        $filterRecords = $listRemarks->count();
        return DataTables::of($listRemarks)
        ->setTotalRecords($totalRecords)
        ->setFilteredRecords($filterRecords)
        ->toJson();
    }
```

I want to Paginate through records returned from `$listRemarks` and need to set custom start and length such as if I put `$start` as 2 and `$limit` as 10 so it must return records from id=3 to id=12 on that page. Also the `recordsFiltered` is not giving correct output when I change $start other than 0. The data resulting by inputting start and limit is correct but the `recordsFilter` is not giving correct count. And this is working fine if I use `paginate()`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try for skip and take

```
public function listRemarks(ListRequest $request)
{
    $query = $this->remarkservice->listRemarks($request);
    $totalRecords = $query->count();
    $limit = $request->input('length') ?? 10;
    $start = $request->input('start') ?? 0;

    $listRemarks = $query->skip($start)->take($limit)->get();
    $filterRecords = $query->count();

    return DataTables::of($listRemarks)
        ->setTotalRecords($totalRecords)
        ->setFilteredRecords($filterRecords)
        ->toJson();
}
```